# How to properly embed settings file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a Settings.settings file which contains a number of different endpoints in it. I want to embed this file into the .dll file so users cannot view or modify the endpoints.

Under the `Build Action` option for the Settings.settings file I see `Embedded Resource`. I read through the MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but I'm still not entirely sure this is the option I want.

Can anyone confirm this does what I want it to, and if not, which option should I select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the embedded build action for storing a Word doc template, but I don't see why you couldn't use it for something else such as an XML file that contains all your settings. Set your build action to embedded and you can reference it as such:

```
var template = "filename.xml" // <-- this is the file you mark to be embedded
Assembly loader = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var rawstream = loader.GetManifestResourceStream(template);
byte[] byteArray = rawstream.ReadToEnd();
```

You will need this using statement:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: Currently I'm using Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName to get the values. Would I now have to manually parse out the XML?

Comment: Yep, that is the downside of using that method. You could always stuff the data into a singleton once you load it in the app's start method. Using singletons is a whole 'nother topic though.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked, but there's another way.

Specify your settings in your web.config or app.config file. Then encrypt the config file when you deploy.

See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx